# I have a problem using to cwtft in matlab

Tags: matlab-guide, wavelet

I am trying to do cwtft on earthquake signals in matlab without give Fs(frequency) and plot scalogram.
how to do it?

```
b=nextpow2(tt);
n=2^b;

s={win2,1/(n-1)};

cwtstruct=cwtft(s,wv);
det=str2double(cwtstruct)
```

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has some built-in examples, that are helpful to take a look, and luckily in your case, it has one [for earthquake time and frequency localizations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/examples/signal-reconstruction-from-continuous-wavelet-transform-coefficients.html).

#### Example 1 Kobe data

```
load kobe
```

to load the time domain data (that I'm guessing).

```
[wt,f] = cwt(kobe,1);
```

Reconstructing the earthquake time data.

```
xrec = icwt(wt,f,[0.030 0.070],'SignalMean',mean(kobe));
```

Plotting and comparing the original time data and the data for frequencies in the range of `[0.030, 0.070]` Hz, which I'm guessing that it would be some technical frequency ranges for earthquakes.

```
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(kobe)
grid on
title('Original Data')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(xrec)
grid on
title('Bandpass Filtered Reconstruction [0.030 0.070] Hz')
```

---

#### Example 2 El Nino data

Loading the El Nino (earthquake) data and obtaining its Continuous Wavelet Transformation of time data:

```
load ninoairdata
[cfs,period] = cwt(nino,years(1/12));
Obtain the inverse CWT for years 2 through 8.

xrec = icwt(cfs,period,[years(2) years(8)]);
```

and plotting the CWT of the reconstructed data using:

```
figure
cwt(xrec,years(1/12))
```

and finally comparing the original time data with the reconstructed data:

```
figure
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(nino)
grid on
title('Original Data')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(xrec)
grid on
title('El Nino Data - Years 2-8')
```

---

You can simply load your own data into these models and see how you'd like to design your methods and analyze your data.